# Trying to create a dynamic webpage Through R markdown,Which needs to pull data from Dataframe inside R

Tags: html, r, r-markdown

I am trying to create a dynamic webpage Through R markdown, I have the code in such a way that the resultant is written to Transact dataframe inside R
The dataframe inside r looks like this

```
    Entered_Commodity_NAme  Commodity_Name
1   Pencil-01-HB                Pencil
```

And I need To write HTML code such that it extracts the data from this Transact dataframe to show the Resultant in proper manner, However i can show the resultant data frame through R chunk, but it will look like below,

The Result of the Commodity Classified with UNSPC code is as below

```
##   Entered_Commodity_NAme Commodity_Name
## 1           Pencil-01-HB                 Pencil
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have everything set up and the question is only how to create a table in markdown.

````
```{r, results="asis"}
library(pander)
pandoc.table(df, style = "rmarkdown")
```
````

for only one row as text

````
```{r, results="asis"}
cat(sprintf("Commodity Name is: %s Parent Category is: %s And UNSPC Code for the Commodity is: %s", df$a[1], df$b[1], df$c[1]))
```
````

Comment: Actually i will get the analysed data in data frame,Having only one row which contains Commodity_Name,Parent_Category,UNSPC_Code, So in R mark down HTML i want to get Like Below,

The Commodity Name is : XXXX
Parent Category is :YYYY
And UNSPC Code for the Commodity is:ZZZZ